# Image button not working with scrollview?

Tags: android, button

Why is back_search image button not working?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/search_img"
 android:background="@drawable/title_bar"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </ImageView>

 <ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/back_search"
 android:background="@drawable/back"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
 android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" />
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/search_title"
 android:text="Search"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"/>


<ScrollView

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <RelativeLayout

 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/ticket_no"
 android:layout_below="@id/search_title"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="70dip"
 android:paddingLeft="10dip"
 android:layout_width="300dip"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:hint="Enter ticket number"

 android:singleLine="true"
 android:textColor="#000000"
 android:background="@drawable/login_text_field"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    >
 </EditText> 

  <EditText
 android:id="@+id/cname"
 android:layout_below="@id/ticket_no"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
 android:paddingLeft="10dip"
 android:layout_width="300dip"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:hint="Enter customer name"
 android:textColor="#000000"

 android:singleLine="true"
 android:background="@drawable/login_text_field"
 android:textSize="15sp"
  >
  </EditText>
 <EditText
android:id="@+id/order_no"
android:layout_below="@id/cname"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:layout_width="300dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Enter order number"
android:textColor="#000000"

 android:singleLine="true"
 android:background="@drawable/login_text_field"
  android:textSize="15sp"
>
</EditText> 

<EditText
 android:id="@+id/card_no"
 android:layout_below="@id/order_no"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
 android:paddingLeft="10dip"
 android:layout_width="300dip"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:hint="Enter card number(last four digits)"
 android:textColor="#000000"
 android:text=""
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:background="@drawable/login_text_field"
 android:textSize="15sp" >
 </EditText>

 <ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/search_btn"
 android:background="@drawable/search_button"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@id/card_no"
 android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
  </ImageButton>
 </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: @Nutan Sharma give some extra information

Comment: @Abhi If I remove scrollview then Imagebutton id=back_search works but when I put it, It is not works

Answer (score 2):

you need to setonclicklistener to the button.

```
        ImageButton b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back_search);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  //do something
            }
        });
```

declaring it in xml it is not enough, in xml you define the look of the button but in the code you must specify the actions