# Android ImageButton ClickEvent not working

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-imagebutton

here is the code, please can anyone simply tell me how to make the onClick event run?

xml file of the activity, which has a navigation-drawer fragment, An Image view, A TextView, An ImageButton

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ContentDescriptionProfileImage"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_pic" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/profileName"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/profileSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/settingsIconDescription"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:onClick="onSettingsIconPressed"
            android:src="@drawable/settings32" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:name="studio25.materialdesign.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"></fragment>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The image of the Screen Looks like [this](http://s9.postimg.org/8rjrs1267/screen_Shot.png)

here is the activity class

```
package studio25.materialdesign;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ProfileView extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    String title = "";
    ImageButton setttingsButton;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_view);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


        NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);

        setttingsButton= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profileSettings);


        /*
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));
        */
    }


    public void onSettingsIconPressed(View v)
    {
        /*
        PopupMenu popupMenu=new PopupMenu(this,v);
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.profile_settings_popup_menu,popupMenu.getMenu());
        popupMenu.show();
        */

        Toast.makeText(this,"Event Click Occured",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

I basically wanted a menu popup on buttonclick, but on debugging realized that my button click is not itself working.

Some tutotials say for popUp menu , minSdkVersion should be 11, even changed that.

Nothing is helping me.
Is my xml erroneous or what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image button not working with scrollview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412206/image-button-not-working-with-scrollview)

Comment: @CurlyCorus it is not the same buddy, in that case button is not working with scroll view and working otherwise. Here it isnt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually like to hook up my callbacks in code (just my personal preference).

```
setttingsButton= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profileSettings);
setttingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"clicked!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

With this you can remove the `onClick` attribute in the xml layout.

If you want a popup window then [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) is a great option.

```
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(some_view_to_show, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)popupHeight, false);
...
popupWindow.showAtLocation(view_to_inject_into, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, (size.y) - (int) popupHeight);
```

then you call `popupWindow.dismiss();` to remove the popup

Your issue could also be that since you are using a `RelativeLayout` each element gets "stacked" on top of each other so you have essentially "buried" your `ImageButton` that you want to click on. So in other words some other view is blocking or consuming your clicks.

Try moving your `ImageButton` to be one of the last elements that you add to the xml file so that it is "on top" of everything else so that it can be clicked.

Alternatively you can try making the containing `LinearLayout` clickable instead of the `ImageButton`.  So you would move the `android:onClick="onSettingsIconPressed"` attribute to the `LinearLayout` that contains the `ImageButton`.

Comment: Thanks but i tried setting the item click listener too.

Comment: I updated my answer.  I think your `ImageButton` is "buried" and it's click event can't be reached.

Comment: yes it was visible but overlayed by the drawer, you got it right. Good Catch.

Comment: I solved it, last night itself but u got it right too, hence you deserve it.